# JavaScript or jQuery event handlers for "Ctrl"/"Shift" + mouse left button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Is it possible to handle such events as:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mouse left button click;
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + mouse left button click;
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + mouse left button click
  by using *JavaScript*, *jQuery* or other framework.

If it is possible, please give a code example for it.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can do something like this (jQuery for the click handler, but any framework works on the part that matters):

```
$(selector).click(function(e) {
  if(e.shiftKey) {
    //Shift-Click
  }
  if(e.ctrlKey) {
    //Ctrl+Click
  }
  if(e.altKey) {
    //Alt+Click
  }
});
```

Just handle whichever you want inside an `if` inside the click handler like I have above.

Answer (score 10):

If you use JQuery plugin called [hotkeys](http://plugins.jquery.com/hotkeys/) you can handle the special keys below.

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'Ctrl+c', fn);
```

Answer (score 9):

More recently I encountered a problem with using `e.ctrlKey` in that, it does not work on MACs.
In a Macintosh, the same effect is achieved using Command+Click.

Since most of the answers above are already assuming usage of jQuery, you can simply use the `e.metaKey` property which is made available by jQuery.

e.g.

```
$(selector).click(function(e) {
  if(e.shiftKey) {
    //Shift-Click
  }
  if(e.metaKey) {
    //Ctrl+Click on Windows & Command+Click on Mac.
  }
  if(e.altKey) {
    //Alt+Click
  }
});
```