# cause key input on onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onclicklistener

I'm trying to allow a user to use a browser's ctrl-plus and ctrl-minus functions through an onclick event but I'm not able to find out how to instruct javascript or jquery to respond as if a key combination has been pressed. Everytime I try to find anything on it I find, instead, instructions on how to get a key combination to trigger an onPress event.

Hitting a bit of a wall.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485345/javascript-or-jquery-event-handlers-for-ctrl-shift-mouse-left-button-click

Comment: So, what you want to do is, zoom in and out, correct? Look for that instead.

Comment: Could you supply us with some of your current code, so we know what you're dealing with as of now?

Comment: Kevin B - yes, I want to zoom in and out of the whole window; not of an image or a div.

Answer (score -1):

Here i have mention key value's  CTRL key - **17** and PLUS SIGN (+) key - **107**,MINUS SIGN (-) key - **109**