# Using shift key and click to go to the next slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe-captivate

Hei guys, i added these lines of code as javascript on succes of a click box in captivate :

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 16) {
       document.Captivate.cpEISetValue('m_VarHandle.cpCmndGotoSlide', 5);
    }
};
```

It does good what it does but after first atempt even if im on another slide and i press shift key it goes to slide 5 :( Another question is, how to set an mousedown and onkeyup event on same button. What i try to achieve is to jump to next slide if i press shift key and i click on a click box.

**EDIT:** new code:

```
document.onmousedown = function (e) {
var currentSlide = document.Captivate.cpEIGetValue('m_VarHandle.cpInfoCurrentSlide');
      if(currentSlide == 5 && e.keyCode == 16){
          document.Captivate.cpEISetValue('m_VarHandle.cpCmndGotoSlide' , 5);
}
};
```

As i think it, should fire the function when i click on it, BUUUT , unfortunately it doesnt work... seems like Captivate doesnt recognize onmousedown event :|

**RE-EDIT :** i figurate out how to make it work. Here's the code :

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
var currentFrame = document.Captivate.cpEIGetValue('m_VarHandle.rdinfoCurrentFrame');
var currentSlide = document.Captivate.cpEIGetValue('m_VarHandle.cpInfoCurrentSlide');

      if(currentSlide == 5 && e.keyCode == 16){
          document.Captivate.cpEISetValue('m_VarHandle.rdcmndGotoFrameAndResume' , 491);

}
};

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
var currentSlide = document.Captivate.cpEIGetValue('m_VarHandle.cpInfoCurrentSlide');

      if(currentSlide == 5){
          document.Captivate.cpEISetValue('m_VarHandle.rdcmndGotoFrameAndResume' , 485);

}
};
```

Now everything's just PERFECT! its exactly what i wanted to do... but it works only on localhost... only when i press F12 in Captivate :( if i try to run exported swf or html from captivate it crush :((( Any ideea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var slide = 4;
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 16) {
       slide++;
       document.Captivate.cpEISetValue('m_VarHandle.cpCmndGotoSlide', slide);
    }
};
```

---

Bassically you want to increment the position (second argument of `cpEISetValue`), in your code, you always set it to 5. Also make sure to reset it when it reaches the max slider position.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the SHIFT key inside the click:

```
var slide = 4;
$('body').click( function (e) {
    if (e.shiftKey) {
       slide++;
       document.Captivate.cpEISetValue('m_VarHandle.cpCmndGotoSlide', slide);
    }
});
```

[check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485345/javascript-or-jquery-event-handlers-for-ctrl-shift-mouse-left-button-click)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a click with a shift key you can use this:

```
$(document).click(
  function(e){
    if(e.shiftKey){
      document.Captivate.cpEISetValue('m_VarHandle.cpCmndGotoSlide', 5);
    }
  }
);
```

the same works with ctrlKey, and altKey

And to change the page fine you need a control variable like this:

```
var current_page = 1;

$(document).click(
  function(e){
    if(e.shiftKey){
      current_page++
      document.Captivate.cpEISetValue('m_VarHandle.cpCmndGotoSlide', current_page);
    }
  }
);
```

I think this is the final code that you need (you maybe need to change document to an id or class that you are using like "#element_id" or ".element_class")