# trigger a function on keypress and click

Tags: php, jquery, html, click

I want to **trigger a function** when I **control+click** on a **html>table>tr** and also **trigger another function** when I don't use a control key.

**Explanation:**

Here I have a **html table**. I have binded on click function to the **table>tr** and a fancybox is show on click of this tr.

But now I want to click the same **tr** within a specific **td** but the first function is getting invoked even if I specify the id of specified **table>tr>td.**

I have applied the **table>tr** a class and href for the fancybox to appear and when I close the fancybox the class and href gets removed according to my wish.

But now When **I wanted to use the same tr** and **click on the td of that tr** and **invoke another fancybox**, the **class and href is being applied to the td** but the **fancybox doesn't appear** belonging to the td but appears belonging to the tr.

```
       $('#tbl').on('click','tbody tr',function(){
                  //fancybox 1 to be appeared
       }); 



       $('#tbl').on('click','tbody tr td#comm',function(){
                  //fancy box 2 to be appeared..
       });
```

If required ctrl or alt or shift keys can be applied

Comment: Have a look at the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485345/javascript-or-jquery-event-handlers-for-ctrl-shift-mouse-left-button-click

Comment: Be aware that ID's in HTML doms are unique. You cannot have multiple TD's with the ID "comm". Thus, if you only want to have one TD with this ID, you can shorten your selector down to: $('#comm).click(function(){ //your function });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.ctrlKey` is `true` when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is pressed (where `e` is the event object from the first parameter of the event handler):

```
$('tbl').on('click', 'tbody tr', function(e) {
   if (e.ctrlKey) {
      //fancybox 1 to be appeared
   }
});
```

Also, you have `shitKey` and `altKey` that are `true` when they are pressed.

Comment: @Ionica Bizau . thanks for the comment. but I want a ctrl click for the second fancybox and for the first one only a normal click

Comment: @kishore You can add an `else` and handle there *normal* clicks.

Comment: having a problem using this, because I even have to render response from the fancybox and display in the td.. when i click it by ctrl+click then I am getting the form load which I seen through debugging tool but sometimes it display the fancybox. please help

Comment: @kishore Ask another question for that. Sounds like another issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464866/issue-with-using-ctrl-and-click-jquery/26467018#26467018

Answer (score 0):

you can also use preventDefault() docs are [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).Hope that helps.