# issue with using ctrl and click jquery

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, fancybox, keypress

```
$('tbl').on('click', 'tbody tr', function(e) {
   if (e.ctrlKey) {
      //fancybox 1 to be appeared
   }
   if(e.shiftKey) {
      //fancybox 2 to be appeared
   }
});
```

**Finding an issue** as below:

//comment

having a problem using this, because I even have to render response from the fancybox and display in the td.. when i click it by ctrl+click then I am getting the form load which I seen through debugging tool but sometimes it display the fancybox.

//comment end

I have used the above coding in a table id tbl and tried to select multiple tr using click event and then get a fancybox. So before that I have used the code as

```
 $('#tbl).on('click','tbody tr',function(e){
      if ($(this).hasClass('fancybox fancybox.ajax')) {
                $(this).removeClass('fancybox fancybox.ajax');
                $(this).css("background", "white");
      }
      else {
           $(this).addClass('fancybox fancybox.ajax');
                    $(this).css("background", "#ffc");
      }
});



   $('tbl').on('click', 'tbody tr', function(e) {
   if (e.ctrlKey) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('fancybox fancybox.ajax')) {
                $(this).removeClass('fancybox fancybox.ajax');
                $(this).css("background", "white");

                //fancybox 1 to be appeared
      }
      else {
           $(this).addClass('fancybox fancybox.ajax');
                    $(this).css("background", "green");
      }
   }
   if(e.shiftKey) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('fancybox fancybox.ajax')) {
                $(this).removeClass('fancybox fancybox.ajax');
                $(this).css("background", "white");
      }
      else {
           $(this).addClass('fancybox fancybox.ajax');
                    $(this).css("background", "yellow");

                    // fancybox 2 to be appeared
      }
   }
});
```

Later tried to implement above code. Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: without html and a better explanation how could anyone here possibly help. What form? What table?

Comment: Please check. Changes made for better understanding

Comment: `$('tbl')` is invalid selector. Otherwise it's still not clear what your issue is.